# How can I solve this integral/differential equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, integral-equations

I was trying to solve a particular problem and I have reduced it down to an integral/differential equation that I do not know how to solve. Here it is in fully explicit form:

$$\int\limits_{t-\frac{d}{2}}^{\frac{d}{2} - t}{\sqrt{1+\bigg(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\bigg)^2} dx = d}$$

I am looking for $y(x, t)$ with these boundary conditions:

$$y\left(t-\frac{d}{2}, t\right) = y\left(\frac{d}{2}-t, t\right) = h$$

$h$ and $d$ are positive real numbers.

I don't know if it'll help but from the context of the problem I know that the $y$ at any constant $t$ is an even function of $x.$

Numerical solutions would also do if it's very hard to solve analytically.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the context of this problem?

Comment: Why do you think these equations have a unique solution?

Comment: Well, I don't know if I modeled it right but I am trying to find $y(x, t)$ for a chain if you clamp it's two ends to a certain height $h$ and the distance between them is $d$. But there is a time element in it, that $d$ is shrinking like $d-t$.

Comment: I know this problem has been solved before but I was trying a different approach, not sure if it'll give me a unique solution.

Comment: Why don't you say that the context is the **length** of a certain rope ?

Comment: The context is the **length** of a certain rope.

Comment: Is the problem that of a rope of length $d$ swaying sideways in a plane containing points of support ? If so, what is its pde or ode of dynamic oscillations?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have a unique solution, since you can have two ropes of equal length span the same two points, yet follow different paths.

Imagine one ropes that's like a "smile" between the two points and another like a "frown", they are reflections about the line directly from one anchor to the next.

The only case where only one solution exists is when it's the distance between the anchors. No solution exists if the prescribed distance is shorter than that.

A case where there is one solution to such a problem is the minimum length case, or the case when you seek a minimum length for two boundary conditions under the influence of weight, this is called a catenary.

Comment: I don't mind having two solutions. I can pick the one that's realistic.

Comment: The problem isn't that there are two solutions, the problem is that it's possible there are an infinite amount. There are realistic versions of this problem formulation, that take minimum length and gravity into account. I'm editing my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Is there any way to prove/disprove that this equation along with these conditions has infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Well, you have two boundary conditions here, along with the condition from the for length from the integral, that's effectively three equations (even if one of them is an integral). If you posit a solution for y of a 3rd order polynomial, one of your parameters would be free, you could choose any value for it as long as the solution remains real.

Comment: What do you mean by "A case where there is one solution to such a problem is the minimum length "? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: What I mean is that rather than prescribing the length as "d" you can formulate this as what's called a variational problem. Then you'll be solving for some y that gives you the minimum length. In this case it would be a straight line between the two boundary conditions, y(x,t) = h. If you look up "calculus of variations catenary", you can find a derivation for the case where the rope is subjected to its own weight.

Comment: Oh yeah I know about that method, you minimize the potential energy of the rope and your functional consists of integral of potential energies at each point. The fact that by minimizing that functional would give the exact curve in question is, I guess, a result from advanced mechanics which I do not understand, yet. I think it's related to something called minimum potetial energy principle. Anyway, thanks for your help.